# Why can the project create an instance of class ViewModel with constructor argument without a factory

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-jetpack

I have read the [artical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965893/cannot-create-an-instance-of-class-viewmodel-in-kotlin).

*When you are initialising the ViewModel through ViewModelProviders without a factory, this means that you can only instantiate a ViewModel which has no constructor arguments.*

The following code is from the project [android-room-with-a-view](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view)

Why can the project create an instance of class ViewModel with constructor argument without a factory in Kotlin?

**Code**

```
wordViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel::class.java)


class WordViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That answer has always been wrong. `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` has always used at least [`AndroidViewModelFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory), which supports the `AndroidViewModel` class which allows automatically making an `Application` class available as a constructor parameter.

Additionally, when using [Fragment 1.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0) or higher, the default factory has been updated to [`SavedStateViewModelFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateViewModelFactory) to also support using `SavedStateHandle` as a constructor parameter as per the [Saved State module with ViewModel guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate).